# Integration with on-prem Microsoft Exchange Solution

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Please forgive this MS Exchange integration 101 question ...

I'm working on a proposal that requires appointments to be inserted, updated and deleted in user's Outlook Calendars.  The customer uses an on-prem MS Exchange solution.  Sorry, I don't yet know the version but I suspect it's a reasonably late version considering they are a large trading bank.

The [EWS Managed API 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633710(v=exchg.80)) seems to meet the project requirements but now I'm reading that parts of that have recently been deprecated (although that seems to only apply to Exchange On-Line).

Is the EWS Managed API the recognized and modern way to integrate with on-prem MS Exchange or should we be considering some other technology.  If there's something else we should be considering, could you point me to that please.

Thanks for all help and advice.

Peter,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EWS remains supported (and no current plans to retire it - for on-prem there is no alternative).  The EWS Managed API is now open source (so not supported by Microsoft as such, but source code is available from Github: https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api).

Comment: Thanks David.  After adding this post and researching further, that was the conclusion that I had come to as well.  However, it's good to have you confirm that.  Thanks.